# How to resolve a hacked website? Webshell wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I think I got hacked...

my wordpress website looks like that yesterday:

[image: website]
and today looks like that:

[image]

I have a backup on the database. I don't know how to handle that now, I run a wordpress on a Centos 7 apache server.

I have received webshell alert from yesterday but first of all I am not really sure what is webshell alert and secondly I have no idea how to resolve that.

Some files with webshell alert are:

```
 /alidata/www/phpwind/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/pop-up-cache.php
 /alidata/www/phpwind/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/wp-infos.php
 /alidata/www/phpwind/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/wp-console.php
 /alidata/www/phpwind/license.php
 /alidata/www/phpwind/wp-res.php
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

This could be a list of (some) compromised files. But you really need to import a full file and database backup, as well you should change all passwords and update WordPress including all plugins to the latest version. Most likely there was an exploit in WP or in any plugin that enabled an attacker to upload a [webshell](https://malware.expert/general/what-is-a-web-shell/).

It will be easier as searching for compromised files because you can forget something.

Comment: Thanks, but as you saw my homepage is already changed. How can I reinstall wordpress and then change back to my original wordpress. TO be honest I am so novice I would love to have few steps to follow to come back to the original situation

Comment: If you have a backup, upload it. If you don't have any backup you should install a fresh copy of wordpress with the version you are using.

Comment: ok but how to change the homepage of my website I mean today it is redirected to another page

Answer (score -1):

Have You used any **Nulled Plugin** ??
If You've then you are boomed !!!
Happened With me too !!!

Comment: What is nulled plugin? I did put few plugin

Comment: Nulled means a Paid Plugin Which is not bought from Official Site ! Downloaded for free from anywhere in Web.

Comment: Ok yes maybe that was the reason

Comment: Yes It can be, coz it happened with me !